# Move and rename Xml files

Tags: linux, unix, ubuntu-16.04, system-administration

I have 500 xml files like these in /home/ss30

0.xml
1.xml
2.xml
.....
500.xml

And 500 folders in /home/ss30/ with these structure
"ss30-Username" while username is always different but all folders starts with ss30-

All folders have the same dir+ archives inside what i want is to put all .xml inside a specific folder inside off each account name off this folder is /templates/.
And once is in /templates/ rename it to templates.xml
Just one aclaration it dosnt matter if 0.xml goes to one folder or another. The structure off all archives is the same but they have different values so all .xml archives look different.

All .xml have different values but same structure
I need 1 xml per folder /templates/.

Ubuntu 16.04 lts minimal

Comment: You have 500 or 501 xml files? Which xml files should go to which ss30-username folder? You wrote "specific" folder, then specify which one? Could you please format what you want to do (punctuation)? You want to copy all xml files to template folder inside each users directory? Which one? Does the structure of the .xml files and the values inside the .xml files matter?

Comment: They are 1335 xml files in total i put just 500 to be an easy and complete number.   All xml files have the same variables inside just different values, it dosnt matther if 0.xml goes to one folder or other will work fine with any user, just i need each user has different xml values= different xml file. No, i want to copy 1 xml file per user, not all files to all users. 1 per user but 1 different always,  not the same. The structure is the same for all, xml files are already created with a java program i can paste code here if you need to understand or paste all folders. Srry if i explain bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bash script will pair a sorted list of xml files with alphabetically sorted list of the `ss30-Username` folders, then move each xml file to a paired destination named `ss30-Username/template/template.xml`.
I didn't test the script, hope it helps you anyway.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -euo pipefail

# change the directory to the first argument
cd "$1"
# all xml files named starting with a number followed by anything, sorted
allxmls=$(printf "%s\n" [0-9]*.xml | sort)
# all user folders sorted
allfolders=$(printf "%s\n" ss30-* | sort)
# check if number of xmls is the same as folders
if [ $(echo "$allxmls" | wc -l) -ne $(echo "$allfolders" | wc -l) ]; then
   echo "ERROR number of xmls is different then number of folders"
   echo "Terminating..."
   exit 1
fi
# pair xmls with folders
pairs=$(paste <(echo "$allxmls") <(echo "$allfolders"))
# for every pair read xml and folder
while read xml folder; do
   # create template folder inside folder
   mkdir -v -p "$folder"/template
   # move xml inside the folder and rename it to template.xml
   mv -v "$xml" "$folder"/template/template.xml
# read pairs
done < <(echo "$pairs")
```

If it is saved into a file named `./script.sh`, add executable rights to it `chmod +x ./script.sh` and run it with the first argument being the path to the folder containing xml files and `ss30-Username` folders, like this `./script.sh /path/to/xml_and_ss30_folders`.

Comment: Thanks dude, i just delete the mkdir cause already exist thath folder inside each username and i also quit the path and i execute from the same directory everything.